# material table checkboxes [React.js]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-table

I already have my checkboxes in the material table in options selection:true i want to know how i can make them work when i click the table refresh anyone here can help me solve this problem? i would appreciate

```
function DataTable() {
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
const columns = [
    { title: 'Data', field: 'hora' },
    { title: 'Paciente', field: 'clientName' },
    { title: 'Médico Veternário', field: 'vet.name' },
    { title: 'Estado', field: 'appointmentState' },
];

const tableIcons = {
    DetailPanel: forwardRef((props, ref) => (
        <ChevronRight {...props} ref={ref} />
    )),
    FirstPage: forwardRef((props, ref) => <FirstPage {...props} ref={ref} />),
    LastPage: forwardRef((props, ref) => <LastPage {...props} ref={ref} />),
    NextPage: forwardRef((props, ref) => <ChevronRight {...props} ref={ref} />),
    PreviousPage: forwardRef((props, ref) => (
        <ChevronLeft {...props} ref={ref} />
    )),
};

useEffect(() => {
    fetch('teste.com')
        .then((resp) => resp.json())
        .then((resp) => setData(resp));
});

return (
    <div style={{ height: 400, width: '100%' }}>
        <MaterialTable
            icons={tableIcons}
            title='Lista Consultas'
            data={data}
            columns={columns}
            options={{
                search: false,
                sorting: true,
                selection: true,
                paging: true,
                pageSize: 5,
                tableLayout: 'auto',
                toolbar: false,
                rowStyle: {
                    backgroundColor: '#FFF',
                    fontSize: '100%',
                },
            }}
        />
    </div>
);}export default DataTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood correctly but, if you want to execute an action over the selected rows, then could do something like this by using a custom action:

[image]

```js
actions={[
          {
            tooltip: "Custom action on selected rows",
            icon: "refresh",
            onClick: (evt, data) => console.log("selected data: ", data)
          }
        ]}
```

The `onClick` event of your custom action gets triggered once you click on the button at the top-right corner, passing as arg (`data`) to that function a list of objects, each representing `rowData` of the selected rows.

Be advised that to use this feature out of the box, the `toolbar` option has to be `true` (default value) and of course, option `selection` also has to be `true`.

Working sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-table-selected-rows-action-i7de6?file=/src/App.js), you could check the [docs](https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/selection) for more examples.

Hope that works for you!